# How to access a value in the application.properties file in Spring Boot app with main method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I have a application.properties in my src/main/resources folder.
it has one property

```
username=myname
```

I have a class

```
public class A
{
    @Value("${username}")
    private String username;

    public void printUsername()
    {
       System.out.println(username);
    }
}
```

when i call printusername function in my main method as follws

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    A object=new A();
    object.printUsername();
}
```

it prints null.
please some one can tell me what i have missed?

Comment: Mark both `username` variable and `printUsername()` method as `static` and try.

Comment: i tried. but didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@Value` annotation, as `@Autowired`, works only if your class is instantiated by Spring IoC container.

Try to annotate your class with `@Component` annotation:

```
@Component
public class A
{
    @Value("${username}")
    private String username;

    public void printUsername()
    {
       System.out.println(username);
    }
}
```

Then in your runnable class:

```
public class RunnableClass {

    private static A object;

    @Autowired
    public void setA(A object){
        RunnableClass.object = object;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        object.printUsername();
    }

}
```

This way should work...